# ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>() fails to deserialize if string contains \n's

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, servicestack

Trying:  `T obj = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(jsonData);`

on a string that has several `\n`'s throughout it.  JayRock's library successfully deserializes this like:  `T obj = (T)JsonConvert.Import(typeof(T), jsonData);`

Is this a bug, or do I need to manually strip out newlines?

Comment: Are thay actually the text `\n` or newline/ascii character 0A?

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/206 related?

Comment: I figured #206 would have been fixed already as its been 2 months.  Not the case?

Comment: Did you pull the latest version from github, or just the release version?

Comment: spender, if i mouse over the jsonData variable, in the preview popup it shows it as \n, however if i view it in "Text Visualizer" it renders each of those a new line.  Not sure if that answers your question, on ascii vs text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I ran into wasn't the \n's, but instead was the lack of public properties on my DTO's.

RE: [Can ServiceStack.Text deserialize JSON to a custom generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771101/can-servicestack-text-deserialize-json-to-a-custom-generic-type)

Answer (score 0):

The debugger preview popup shows actual linebreaks as \n so that the preview remains single line. The text visualizer shows linebreaks correctly.

This implies to me that the JSON itself is broken, because newlines ***should*** be encoded with `\n`.

Linebreaks in strings are illegal in Javascript, and thus also in JSON.

*If this doesn't happen to the the issue*: the nuget version was published 1st Oct, but there's a commit in github dated 3rd Oct with comment "fix whitespace issues hopefully once and for all". Worth trying.