# Can ServiceStack.Text deserialize JSON to a custom generic type?

Tags: c#, json, generics, serialization, servicestack

Example is the following, where T is some DTO that I expect to get 1...n back matching the resultCount.  This loaded up fine using Jayrock JsonConvert, however is just returning a new JsonResult to me when trying to deserialize the same json text that worked in Jayrock.

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonResult<T>
{
  public int resultCount = 0;
  public T[] results;
}
```

I thought this might be an issue that I asked about at [ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>() fails to deserialize if string contains \n's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765072/servicestack-text-jsonserializer-deserializefromstringt-fails-to-deserialize), however even stripping out those \n's still doesn't allow deserialization to succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) does support generics but only serializes **public properties** which is the problem here.

Also the `[Serializable]` attribute has no significance in most (all?) serailizers outside of .NET, including all of ServiceStack's serializers.

Comment: I believe the [Serializable] is still lingering from some old xml serialization of this object type.  I'll take a look though.